# Error: reference to a non shared member requires an object reference occurs in general module

Tags: vb.net

My code: (GeneralModule.vb)

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module GeneralModule

    Public Sub ClearTxt()
        Dim t As Control
        For Each t In FormReceipt.Controls()
            If TypeOf t Is TextBox Then
                t.Text = ""
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

I'm getting error at *FormReceipt.Controls()* as **BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.**
Help plz...

Comment: Where is that code called from? If it is from `FormReceipt` then you could add a parameter like `Public Sub ClearTxt(frm as Form)`, call it with `ClearTxt(Me)` and use `frm` to refer to the form.

Answer (score 1):

`FormReceipt` is the name of a class. You need a reference to an instance of that class.

VB.Net provides default instances of each form in variables with the same name as the class, but there are certain places where you can't access those instances that way. For example, if this code is in a different class library, that separate assembly doesn't know or care about the default form instances; it only sees the imported type names. Certain project settings can also turn these off.

At the point where you show the form, or are about to show the form, you'll be able to find a reference for the instance you need. When you you say something like `FormReceiptVariable.Show()` or `FormReceiptVariable.ShowDialog()`, you need to assign that variable somewhere you will also be able to access from the code in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Drop a button on your form, double click it and paste this modified version of your code into the click handler:

```
    For Each t as Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf t Is TextBox Then
            t.Text = ""
        End If
    Next
```

If, as per the commenter, you want the code to be outside your form, you'll have to give the controls collection you want to search, to the module:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module GeneralModule

    Public Sub ClearTextboxesInCollection(x as ControlControlCollection)
        For Each t as Control In x
            If TypeOf t Is TextBox Then
                t.Text = ""
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

And call it like this from a button on your form (or some other triggering place where "Me" refers to the form that you want to clear):

```
    GeneralModule.ClearTextboxesIn(Me.Controls)
```

It's worth noting that controls can be hierarchically nested, and a Panel will have a .Controls collection that could contain textboxes so naively enumerating them wont dig into any panels and find the controls

To this end you might want to consider something more like:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module GeneralModule

    Public Sub ClearTextboxesInCollection(x as ControlControlCollection)
        For Each t as Control In x
            If TypeOf t Is TextBox Then
                t.Text = ""
            End If
            If t.HasChildren Then
                ClearTextboxesInCollection(t.Controls)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: This won't work. He wants the code to live in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

> BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

This error is because of this `For Each t In FormReceipt.Controls()` that's not an instance of `FormReceipt`; probably the default.

To fix you need an instance of `FormReceipt` for example: `Private fr As FormReceipt = New FormReceipt()` if you don't have one *already* otherwise just assign the variable.

Then use that variable/instance to get the controls...

```
 For Each t In fr.Controls()
```

Comment: Creating a `New FormReceipt` is unlikely to be helpful. There's almost certainly already a specific instance he needs a reference to.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn exactly, I was finishing up a sentence to say otherwise... but we don't know that. The point is, they need a reference to that instance.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ @JoelCoehoorn thank you, above code worked for me, still, it does not clears the text boxes on the form. I called `ClearTxt()` in button click handler.